# How to dump a postgres db excluding one specific table?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to use `pg_dump` to backup `postgres` database content. I only want to ignore one specific table containing cached data of several hundred GB.

How could I achieve this with pg_dump?

Comment: Please read the manual there is a `--exclude-table` parameter: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: [Nothing wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167765/253241) with a question like this. Just because something can be found in a manual somewhere, doesn't make it a bad question for SO. I've posted the answer as a community wiki.

Comment: @LondonRob it's funny that the correct answer is the first result in google if you search by the question subject.

Comment: This isn't really the place for this discussion, particularly because [it's been had before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262548/2071807) and [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191653/should-i-ask-a-question-that-is-easily-google-able) and [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html), there is an option to `--exclude-table` which excludes tables from the dump by matching on a pattern (i.e. it allows wildcards):

> -T table
>   --exclude-table=table Do not dump any tables matching the table pattern. The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for
>   -t. -T can be given more than once to exclude tables matching any of several patterns.
>
> When both -t and -T are given, the behavior is to dump just the tables
>   that match at least one -t switch but no -T switches. If -T appears
>   without -t, then tables matching -T are excluded from what is
>   otherwise a normal dump.

There are a few examples [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES).

Comment: FWIW, --exclude-table was problematic for me due to some keys etc. that existed on the table but --exclude-table-data worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the same in the script

```
#!/bin/bash

CKUPNUM=3
BACKUPDIR=/home/utrade/dbbackup
DBBACKUP_FILENAME=Database_dump.sql
TARFILE=Database_dump_$(date +%d%h%y).tgz

#####Variables Set
DBUSER=mutrade
DBPASSWD=utrade123
DBNAME=mutradedb


cd $BACKUPDIR
export PGPASSWORD=$DBPASSWD
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_dump -f $DBBACKUP_FILENAME $DBNAME --exclude-table-data='appmaster.ohlc_*' -U $DBUSER
tar czf $TARFILE $DBBACKUP_FILENAME
rm -f $DBBACKUP_FILENAME
#removing old/Extra backups
backups_count=`ls -lrt | wc -l`
if [[ $backups_count -gt $BACKUPNUM ]]
then

find $BACKUPDIR -mtime +30 -type f -delete

fi
```